# I cannot understand why this is not valid housing

Tags: terraria

These two houses  are exactly like the house on the left. I have taken the wall out and put it back in multiple times and I really don't[image] know what is going on this is making my brain melt

Comment: Are you standing in front of a chair?

Comment: Yeah, I am standing in front of the chair

Comment: I'm meeting all of those requirements

Comment: Are you people not listening? I meet all of those requirements. When there is not tables/light in there it says this room needs a table/light. When I put them in it says this housing is not valid.

Comment: The other houses are higher up, maybe this one is too far underground..?

Comment: How recently did you grow the corruption in that dungeon brick room? Looks like you're only around 28 blocks away from it...

Comment: As the first answer to the question closed as duplicate, "The room must be at least approximately 42 blocks away from any corruption."